# Which test do I need to find out if there is a significant difference between two lists of numbers and how can this be performed on R?

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to find out whether there is a significant difference between two lists of numbers of differing lengths (one list has 25 values and the other has 104). Both lists are non normally distributed and they are independent of one another (as in not a before & after measurements or something along those lines). Could someone help me on what test is needed and how to perform this test on R ?

out of interest which test would be suitable for the same situation where the data is normally distributed (and how would this be done on R)?

Comment: You need to apply the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Test.  `set.seed(123)
wilcox.test(mpg~am, data = mtcars, exact=FALSE)`

Comment: @TarJae I'm just curious... what does the ```set.seed(123)``` do here? Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the [Wilcoxson test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is used for this.
You can read up on it [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/unpaired-two-samples-wilcoxon-test-in-r)

How to do it in R:

```r
### Part 1: Creating some data to work with
short = rpois(25, 10) # Create a random list of 25 values
long = rpois(104, 3) # Create a random list of 104 values
boxplot(short, long) # Plot the two lists

### Part 2: Running the Wilcoxon test
wilcox.test(short, long)
```

Output:

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  short and long
W = 2543, p-value = 8.87e-14
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```